# Flutter Inicializar textformfield con patron bloc

Tags: flutter, widget

Tengo un proyecto de flutter con el patron bloc en este consumo la data del api y la mando a las vistas

esta en mi clase bloc

```
  final distribuidorProvider =  DistribuidorProvider();

  final _nombreController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _marcaController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _celularController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  //Recuperar los datos del stream
    Stream<String> get nombreStream => _nombreController.stream.transform(validarBasica);
    Stream<String> get emailStream => _emailController.stream.transform(validarEmailOriginal);
    Stream<String> get marcaStream => _marcaController.stream.transform(validarBasica);
    Stream<String> get passwordStream => _passwordController.stream.transform(validarBasica);
    Stream<String> get celularStream => _celularController.stream.transform(validarCelular);

  Stream<bool> get formValidUpdateStream => CombineLatestStream.combine5(nombreStream, emailStream, marcaStream, passwordStream, celularStream, (a, b, c, d, e) => true);



  //Obtener el ultimo valor ingresado a los streams
  String get nombre => _nombreController.value;
  String get email => _emailController.value;
  String get marca => _marcaController.value;
  String get password => _passwordController.value;
  String get celular => _celularController.value;

  //Insertar Valores al stream
  Function(String) get changeNombre => _nombreController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeMarca => _marcaController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get changeCelular => _celularController.sink.add;



  dispose() {
    _nombreController?.close();
    _emailController?.close();
    _marcaController?.close();
    _passwordController?.close();
    _celularController?.close();
  }

  ObtenerInformacion()async{
    PreferenciasUsuario _pref = PreferenciasUsuario();
    String id = _pref.idUsuario;
    var dist = await distribuidorProvider.obtenerInformacion(id);
    changeNombre(dist.nombre);
    changeEmail(dist.email);
    changeMarca(dist.marca);
    changeCelular(dist.cellphone);
  }
}
```

y en mi vista tengo varios widgets de textform field que son rellenados con streambuilders

```
    Widget _inputEmail(PerfilBloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.emailStream,
      // initialData: bloc.email,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        return Container(
          child: TextFormField(
            initialValue: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : "",
            // initialValue: "aaaaaaaa@outlook.com",
            onChanged: (value) => bloc.changeEmail(value),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error : null,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: "Ingrese Correo Electronico",
            ),
            autofocus: false,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

este es un widget de ejemplo el detalle es que al momento de hacer el initvalue no muestra la data en el widget pero si yo pongo otro valor si lo inicializa ya comprobe poniendo el print en el snapshot.data y si tiene la data correctamente pero no lo pinta alguna sugerencia ?

dejo mi vista completa en el build invoco el metodo del bloc para traer la data de la api

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(children: _menu(),),

      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Actualizar Perfil"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: size.width * 0.8,
            child: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.1,
                  ),
                  _inputEmail(bloc),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  _inputNombre(bloc),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  _inputMarca(bloc),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  _inputCelular(bloc),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  _inputPassword(bloc),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                  ),
                  _crearBotonAceptar(bloc)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: te refieres a initialData o initialValue ? cual de los 2 no te funciona

Comment: ninguno de los dos amigo ninguno me funciona pongo uno y pongo otro no pinta nada . en el textformfield

Comment: el String get email => _emailController.value; es vacio al inicio? entonces snapshot.data también será nulo o vacio

Comment: claro y al poco tiempo ejecuto el metodo de obtenerdatos de mi bloc donde se manda la data al stream

Comment: hmm pon el código que falla para revisar

Comment: ya respondi amigo es lo que te menciono si puedes ver en mi patron bloc tengo un metodo llamado obtenerInformacion en este yo hago consulta a mi api . y despues cuando obtengo la informacion del usuario la mando a los streams

Comment: Dices que al momento de iniciar no muestra la data, pero en realidad tiene DATA? que data tiene? de donde recibe data? pintaste los valores para ver si llegan ?

Comment: si amigo si puedes observar tengo un print en el metodo de snapshot de _email cuando pasa por ese print claro que pinta la data que tiene pero no la pinta en el widget

Comment: cuantas veces pinta print(snapshot.data); ?  puedes agregar esto : print("data: ${snapshot.data}"); para ver cuantas veces pinta, OJO que initialValue solo recibe el valor por primera vez, luego de eso es inmutable, asi que no se puede actualizar, para eso debes usar el TextEditingController

Comment: tienes mucha razon la primera vez viene null lo pinto dos veces y es en la segunda donde se resuelve y viene la data

Comment: el problema es que si yo hago el controller  y lo hago de esta manera cuando  modifico el valor de este input el cursor se mueve hasta el inicio y tira un error de text selection index was clamped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como puse en los comentarios, el `initialValue` del widget `TextFormField` solo se inicia una vez, luego de eso no importa los valores que le pases, el `TextFormField` ya fue creado y ese valor no se actualiza.

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Actualizar los valores con el `TextEditingController` que veo que no
   lo estás usando.
2. Hacer una validación previa antes de crear el `TextFormField`.

Para la 1era opción te recomiendo este Link:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Para la 2da opción lo puedes hacer así:

```dart
  Widget _inputEmail(PerfilBloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.emailStream,
      // initialData: bloc.email,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        return Container(
          child: snapshot.hasData ? TextFormField(
            initialValue: snapshot.data,
            onChanged: (value) => bloc.changeEmail(value),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error : null,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: "Ingrese Correo Electronico",
            ),
            autofocus: false,
          ) : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

NOTA: ojo que esto funcionará con el caso de uso que mencionaste, cuando al inicio ya tienes un valor o lo cargas, de otro modo no se mostrará el `TextFormField`.

Lo ideal sería que al entrar a `_inputEmail` sepas si tiene un valor inicial o no para hacer otra validación aquí :  `child: snapshot.hasData ? TextFormField(`